# textField SlideAnimation when starting initial view controller

Tags: ios, animation

I need to create a right slide animation for TextField 1 and left slide animation for TextField2 . I tried to accomplish first right slide animation, but there is a problem.  I have an slide animation, but there is another textfield under my animation textfield which doesn't move from it's constraints. I do not really understand why.

here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PasswordField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       
        emailField.center.x = self.view.frame.width + 50
      
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
            self.emailField.center.x = self.view.frame.width/2
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: A bit confusing, because your code only references animating one `UITextField`, not two. However, if you're adding your views and giving them constraints in Storyboard (indicating by the `@IBOutlet` in your code), you need to animate changes to the constraints... you will have problems trying to explicitly change frames (e.g. `self.emailField.center.x = ...`)

Comment: Well I didn't animate second TextField yet  because I have such a problem with first one. Yeah, I do views and constraints in storyboard. Is there any other way to create slide animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Storyboard looks similar to this:

[image]

Two text fields, with Top constraints, Width constraints equal to 80% of the view width, and CenterX constraints to the view's CenterX

Ctrl-Drag from each `.centerX` constraint to your view controller code to create `@IBOutlet` connections to the constraints:

```
@IBOutlet var emailCenterX: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var passwordCenterX: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Your Storyboard will now look like this:

[image]

And you can move / animate the views by setting their `.constant` values at run-time:

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var PasswordField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet var emailCenterX: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var passwordCenterX: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var viewWidth: CGFloat = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // move the textFields "off-screen"
        emailCenterX.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        passwordCenterX.constant = -UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // reset the centerX constraints to the center of the view
        emailCenterX.constant = 0
        passwordCenterX.constant = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it helped, however, animation looks pretty weird, I'll try to fix it,